# Mayor de 3 numeros del 500 a 1500

Tags: c, dev-c++

mi duda es como hago para que el programa me reconozca solamente números del 500 al 1500, porque pongo cualquier numero y me los toma, pero necesito que solo sea del 500 al 1500

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 
 int main()
 {
 int N1, N2, N3;
 
 printf("Ingrese el primer numero: ");
    scanf("%d", &N1 );
    printf("ingrese el segundo numero: ");
    scanf("%d", & N2);
    printf ("Ingrese el tercer numero: ");
    scanf("%d", &N3);

    if (N1 > N2 && N1 > N3){
        printf ("el numero mayor es: %d ");
    }
    else if ( N2 > N1 && N2 >N3){
        printf ("el numero mayor es: %d");
        
    }
    else if ( N3 > N1 && N3 > N2){
        printf( "el mayor numero es: %d");
    }
    else if ( N1 > N3 && N1 == N2){
        printf("El numero mayor es: %d" );
    }
    else if ( N1 > N2 && N2 == N3){
        printf (" el numero mayor es: %d" );
    }
    else if ( N2 > N1 && N2 ==N3){
        printf("el mayor numero es: %d");
    }
    else{
        printf (" Los tres numeros son iguales ");
        
        
 }
 
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: `if (N >= 500 && N <=1500)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tan solo tienes que volver a pedir numero cada vez que no se cumpla la condicion deseada. Esto lo puedes hacer con un ciclo `do while`:

```
 do{
    printf("Ingrese el primer numero: ");
    scanf("%d", &N1 );
    if(N1 < 500 || N1 > 1500)
        printf("Ingrese numero entre 500 y 1500\n");
        
}while(N1 < 500 || N1 > 1500);
```

Despues creo que te sobran algunos `if` donde compruebas que numero es el mayor o si los tres son iguales. Además te falta poner la variable correspondiente al final de los `printf`

Te dejo un ejemplo completo:

```
 int main()
 {
    int N1, N2, N3;

    do{
        printf("Ingrese el primer numero: ");
        scanf("%d", &N1 );
        if(N1 < 500 || N1 > 1500)
            printf("Ingrese numero entre 500 y 1500\n");
        
    }while(N1 < 500 || N1 > 1500);

    do{
        printf("Ingrese el segundo numero: ");
        scanf("%d", &N2 );
        if(N2 < 500 || N2 > 1500)
            printf("Ingrese numero entre 500 y 1500\n");
        
    }while(N2 < 500 || N2 > 1500);

    do{
        printf("Ingrese el tercer numero: ");
        scanf("%d", &N3 );
        if(N3 < 500 || N3 > 1500)
            printf("Ingrese numero entre 500 y 1500\n");
        
    }while(N3 < 500 || N3 > 1500);

    if (N1 > N2 && N1 > N3){
        printf ("el numero mayor es: %d ",N1);
    }
    else if ( N2 > N1 && N2 >N3){
        printf ("el numero mayor es: %d",N2);
    
    }
    else if ( N3 > N1 && N3 > N2){
        printf( "el mayor numero es: %d",N3);
    }
    else{
        printf (" Los tres numeros son iguales ");       
 }

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA AMIGOOOOOOOOO TE AMOOOOOOOOOOO